# touch command not working for multiple files?

Tags: linux, ksh

I am not sure why `touch filename{1..10}` is not working in my k-shell?

Does it necessary to make a loop in this case? If so what is wrong here:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
for i in {1..10}
do
    touch file${i}
done
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Check the ksh version.  `ksh --version`.  The canonical korn shell today is ksh93.  It looks like yours could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original `touch file[i]` creates a single file with the name "file[i]".

```
$ touch file[i]
$ ls
file[i]
$
```

As Sun's older ksh88 dialect does not understand *brace expansion*, you need to use something like:

```
i=1 && while ((i<=10)); do
    ((i+=1))
    touch filename${i}
done
```

Comment: What was the result?  Also, we still don't know the [version of your ksh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459891/touch-command-not-working-for-multiple-files/19469934?noredirect=1#comment28873616_19459891), and run a `uname -a` for extra info about your system.

Comment: ver: 11/16/88i SUNOS..the result is file{1..10}.